# Django template context processors vs passing parameters to render_to_response

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to use a number of custom context processors to render some of my template data instead of passing the data every time to the render_to_response method.

Is there any disadvantage (eg memory usage)  when adding many context processors to a django project ?

Are there any recommendations for when using context processors instead of passing the data to the templates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have to use in a lot of templates (almost in every template), something like the user, or DEBUG or other parameters that these don't have a lot of cost, you must use a context processors. In other case passing to render_to_response

Comment: So there is a cost to using context processors ?

Comment: This is obvious. Every line the code has a cost. But if you want something in the 90% of the templates, in the other rest  (10%) your view will be something more slow, but you will win clearness in the 90%. This is a balance... For example I "never" (never say never) will do a insert into the data base in a context processor, I never call to the external service, etc, but access to the settings, simples query to the database etc of course

Comment: So if I add a template context processor that queries the database to get data, this query will be executed every time a random view is displayed (even if does not use that context processor) or only when the view uses that specific context processor ?

Comment: the query will be executed every time. however you can use caching to reduce the overhead -  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/  However I really would not worry about the speed at this stage. Do whatever makes for the cleanest code, then use something like the django-debug-toolbar to see if your context processor adds a significant overhead and only then should you spend valuable time on optimising. Often the overhead of the query will be negligble and not worth wasting time on optimisation. https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar